# RSpec tests hanging just on new machine OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I just got a newer MBP and after installing brew, RVM, MySQL, bundler, etc. and getting my gemset set up, test database created, I tried to run my spec suite using parallel_tests:
`rake parallel:spec[4]`

It starts chugging along then just hangs. It waits 60s or more before it gets uncorked and chugs along for another set of green dots (~130), and then repeat. In fact the delay after each pause seems to get longer. When it hangs the spinner in the terminal tab goes away and comes back when it wakes back up.

The same test suite running in parallel on my old MBP doesn't periodically hang.

I have no idea where to start to diagnose where it is hung, what in the environment could be different between the two machines.

Running spec tests in serial seems to hang between each assertion (dot) as well.

I appreciate any tips.

Other env details:
ruby 2.0.0p451, Redis 2.8.13, Rails 3.2.19, MySQL 5.6.20

Comment: Do you run any feature specs by any chance?

Comment: @PNY, no, no feature specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - Net:HTTP (via css_parser, via premailer, via premailer_rails) was taking 60s to fail locating css referenced in email template on 'bad' machine.

Details:
Narrowed down the delay on the 'bad' machine to the call in css_parser's read_remote_file where  the css was `http://my-machine-mb:3001/stylesheets/email.css`. For some reason, Net::HTTP was taking the full 60s to fail to find. On 'good' machine, that fails within 5s. Good news is I realized that my unit tests were inlining css for email when it doesn't need to.  I still need to figure out why the request takes 60s to fail on the 'bad' machine.